# WPF Data grid bonded tooltip is blinking by table content binding refresh

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, tooltip

I have a WPF application that has a data grid with an observable collection bonded to it, representing its data.
The data in the collection will apply to cell's content and row's tooltip, as you can see in the following xaml code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelItems}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Path=Color}"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Notes}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                </DataGrid>
```

The view model holds of course the corresponding list:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ViewModelItems
    {
        get { return model.ModelItems; }
    }
```

and in the model:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _modelItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ModelItems { get { return _modelItems ; } }
```

The class of Item is as following:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is like that:

In model scope I have a trigger that updates ModelItems every second, so I can get the "Time" data grid fields synchronized every second.

The "Notes" field that stands behind the ToolTip property doesn't change. When I stand on a row to see the tool tip it blinks each time the table refreshes its content - means every second the tooptip disappears and returns (though"notes" stays the same)

Is there a way to avoid the tool tip from blinking?

I even tried to update ModelItems not by clear/add/remove , by updating the properties "Time" "Color" directly, and leaving the "Notes" property without touching it (in this case I had to implement ObservableCollection listen to its properties PropertyChanged event and raising CollectionChanged event and Item class to raise PropertyChanged event whenever updating the relevant properties)
but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ItemsSource "ViewModelItems" is being created again everytime the getter of ViewModelItems is called.
Try

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> viewModelItems;
public ObservableCollection<Item> ViewModelItems
{
get 
{ 
if(viewModelItems == null)
{
viewModelItems = model.ModelItems; 
}
return viewModelItems;
}
}
```

catch the property change of modelitems on viemodel and update the properties in viewModelItems. This should help with the tooltip blinking.